# Python, Pymongo, Mock : Patching a pymongo collection

Tags: python, mocking, pymongo

I am trying to patch a pymongo `collection` for test purpose, using `mock.patch`.

So lets consider the 2 following databases: the first one is the real one, that the production code connects to. The second one is used only for test purposes.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

mongo=MongoClient()
mongo.real_db.data.insert_many(
    [{'index': i , 'value':1} for i in range 100])

mongo.test_db.data.insert_many(
    [{'index': i , 'value':'test'} for i in range 100])
```

A function from the production code does the following:

```
def get_data():
    print(list(mongo.real_db.data.find()))
```

I would like to patch that function in my test suite so that it connects to the test database instead.

I tried

```
from mock import patch 

@patch('__main__.mongo.real_db.data', new=mongo.test_db.data)
def test_get_data():
    get_data()

test_get_data()
```

But it still connects to the real db.
Anyone can help on how to patch the real db properly with the test one?

Answer (score 0):

`patch.object` can be applied as a context manager for mocking an object

```
def test_get_data():
    with patch.object(mongo, 'real_db', new=db):
        get_data()
```

or as a decorator

```
@patch.object(mongo, 'real_db', new=db)
def test_get_data():
    get_data()
```